# .dockerignore is not used for docker-compose build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm ignoring `**/static` in `.dockerignore` but `/static` dir is in the built image.

I'm running `docker-compose build my-image`

Directory layout is like this

```
./context (root)
  .dockerignore
  dockder-compose.yml
  production
     django
        DockerFile
```

I copied .dockerignore to where `DockerFile` is, but still no difference.

Comment: and where is your .dockeringore located? And where is your Dockerfile located? in same folder?

Comment: @MazelTov updated my directory structure, no it's not in the same folder.

Comment: Which of those folders is your build directory? Can you include an [mcve] with the contents of the ignore file, compose file, and Dockerfile, along with the directory layout?

Comment: and where is the /static folder located,... it is missing from your Dir structure

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that in `docker-compose` context, `.dockerignore` does not work like `.gitignore` in terms of patterns ... it expects explicit file/folder locations. I had the same issue where I was trying to ignore `.env` files in a `/api` folder with just `.env` in the `.dockerignore` file. The `.env` in `/` would be excluded, but `/api/.env` would be included. By adding a separate line to explicitly declare `/api/.env`, now the `docker-compose build` is correctly excluding those files:

```
.env
node_modules
/api/.env
/api/node_modules
```

Comment: You can use **/node_modules now so that all level will be ignored, including the root.